Custom WP Query with neither ASC or DESC
I have found several posts like my question but never really found a good answer.
I have ACF fields on Posts. One of them is a radio, with 3 values (For Sale, Pending and Sold).
I have used a Query to order them:
add_action( 'elementor/query/trier_articles', function( $query ) {
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'status' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', array('meta_value' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC') );
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
});

It's working, but now I would like to order them like this : Pending -> For Sale -> Sold.
Could I somehow use meta_key ? Or is there a way to process each meta_value to make it work like I want?
Thank you!

Don't think the effort worth it to do it with generating appropriate mysql statements as you can just use three queries, or sort the posts after you have the results of the query with both ways resulting in a mostly readable code. Main reason not to choose the above is if performance is critical.
Another option is to use some different meta field and store some integer value representing the 3 states, but if you are using a plugin that generates the property value status this might be hard work to figure all the place in which the new meta field can be added.
And if you feel like a mysql guru you can probably order by the value of FIND_IN_SET. You will need to figure out which filter to use to override the
query. One pointer is this snippet - https://gist.github.com/mikeschinkel/6402058#file-find-in-set-php but I didn't inspect that code.

Thank you for your input!
I have already read about the find in set, but it seems pretty hard to implement for such a small fix.
You gave me a few ideas.
So either can I create 2 queries and fuse them.
My first idea was to create a "order" field and be done with it... But I can probably automate something to change the value of order when the data is created or saved. I think i'm going to try this one first!
